# how to install laravel project under add on domain

Tags: hosting, sharing

I have checked almost all questions related to installing laravel on shared hosting. but, still confused.

I have two addon domain names which are hosted under a shared hosting on godaddy. both on different accounts. the one addon domain name has a laravel website which is perfectly working. so i have copied all the files and upload them to the other addon domain name on another account. also imported the database and made the changes on the env file. i don't know what to do after this.

i have seen other similar questions. they suggest copying the files from the "public" directory of laravel to public_html, but i couldn't find that directory. also i have another website under the public_html and can't overwrite any file.

i have installed laravel using drush. can't go any further.